# For Each Loop Iteration Count

Tags: vb.net, foreach, iteration

Can we keep track of our **iteration** in our loop when we use a **For Each**? I like to use the For Each loops for looping through my objects but I cannot seem to find a way to keep an index of where I'm at in the loop. Unless of course I create my own ...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you want to have an index, use a `For`-loop instead of a `For each`. That's why it exists.

```
For i As Int32 = 0 To objects.Count - 1
    Dim obj = objects(i)
Next
```

Of course nothing prevents you from creating your own counter:

```
Dim counter As Int32 = 0
For Each obj In objects
    counter += 1
Next
```

or you can use Linq:

```
Dim query = objects.Select(Function(obj, index) "Index is:" & index)
```

Comment: ah okay, yeah that's what i figured. just wanted to make sure! thanks!

Answer (score 1):

There's no built-in solution yet. Of course you know how to do it with a counter but [this](http://www.yoda.arachsys.com/csharp/miscutil/usage/smartenumerable.html) maybe what you are looking for (By [Jon Skeet](https://stackoverflow.com/users/22656/jon-skeet))

Answer (score 0):

You can do it like this:

```
 Dim index as integer = 0
 For Each item in list
      'do stuff
      index += 1
 Next
```

Off course, depending on the collection your iterating over, there is no guaranteeing that `item` will be the same as `list.item(index)`, but wether or not that matters depends on what you are doing.

```
For index as integer = 0 to list.count - 1
     Dim item = list.item(index)
     'do stuff
Next
```

That is the other alternative if you need `item` to be the same as `list.item(index)`.